# Regex, gather scrape information on 1 or more lines

Tags: regex

I am relatively new to Regex so still learning a lot.

I am trying to gather data for our client system, the part I am trying to capture is the address. Usually the address is on 1 line however we do get moments where it can cover 2 lines

I am currently using the PRCE method.

example:

Home address Randana Cove 805A/93 Thomas Street,
Subtance ZA 60087

https://regex101.com/r/xW6bsv/1

Is there a way to scrape the address, after Home address *Randana Cove 805A/93 Thomas Street,
Subtance ZA 60087*
to cover 1 line or more if it covers multiline.

It seems from the regex101 that there is a new line in this example where there usually isn't.

So when trying to scrape the data accurately I want the regex to be dynamic if possible or  write a solution that will capture 1 or more lines.

Thank you again for your guidance

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xW6bsv/2 will capture 1 or two lines.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xW6bsv/3 - variable number lines

Comment: @PM77-1
Thank you very much for that.